# Transit via South Africa for an undesirable person

Tags: transit, overstaying, south-africa

I have a scheduled flight from Zimbabwe to the USA, but my flight will connect in South Africa. I am not sure whether I will be allowed to transit or whether I'm also banned from transiting. I overstayed and got an undesirable person ban.